# Convert stereo audio to mono in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, audio, mono

I have an audio file with extension .raw and recorded in stereo, and I need to convert it to mono with Node. I'm not able to find a example of  how to do it this process or a library.

Any help would be great

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following library
https://github.com/fluent-ffmpeg/node-fluent-ffmpeg to use ffmpeg on node.

And following to convert to stereo to mono via ffmpeg
`ffmpeg -i stereo.flac -ac 1 mono.flac`

Just pass the above options to ffmpeg via the library.
Here's my code that seems to work

```
var FFmpeg = require('fluent-ffmpeg');

var command = FFmpeg({
    source: 'test.webm'
}).addOption('-ac', 1)
.saveToFile('out.mp3');
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I having the following error:

Error: Cannot find ffmpeg.

I did a npm install fluent-ffmpeg defore run the code

Comment: You need to install ffmpeg binary for your system as well. You can download it from here for your OS https://www.ffmpeg.org/download.html